# Not a day goes by that we can’t at least serve one other human being by making deposits of unconditional love

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the following quote by Stephen Covey mean ?

> Not a day goes by that we can’t at least serve one other human being
>   by making deposits of unconditional love

Especially the part "serve one other human being
by making **deposits of unconditional love**"

Comment: Which word don't you understand?

Comment: "deposits of unconditional love" mostly

Comment: Well it's an extremely popular fad term, group of fad terms, in the USA, over the last say 15-20 years.

Comment: Simply **google 'love deposits'** to see a huge number of books, articles, films, etc, using this phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Steven Covey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Covey) got his start by writing books about effective time management.  Doing so, he became a management guru in the field of business.  With the phrase "making deposits of unconditional love," he is writing to his audience.  He is economizing love.  He is figuratively quantifying love like it's money that can be put in a bank.  He is implying that those metaphorical deposits of love result in both the investment into and the increase of others as well as result in return on investment for the depositor.  He is essentially monetizing the notion of karma.  Why is he doing that?  Because, again, he is writing to his audience, to his acolytes, which are by and large people who work in business.  If he were instead speaking to bees, he might more aptly say, "making honey combs of unconditional love."

UPDATE:

@Benjamin, what does "both result in investment into and increase of others" mean? That's the only phrase that I think might be unclear to the reader. (You've answered me above. Do you want to include that explanation in your answer? ) +1 – Mark Hubbard 13 mins ago

@Mark Hubbard: Again, it's analogous to banking. When we put money in a bank, that money doesn't sit in an empty room but is instead then used to invest in others and cause their lot to increase. So, when we make deposits into a bank, we ourselves are making that investment into others. When we love others unconditionally, that love not only comes back to us with interest and dividends, but also it results in others investing and spending and earning love, too. It helps build an entire economy of unconditional love, an economy in which it's unconditional love that is being exchanged.  Unless someone has a solid conceptualization of banking, it's going to be hard to understand. As I said, Covey was targeting an audience.

Comment: Great as always. May ask you why human being was used and why not person or people?

Comment: @haha : You'd have to ask Steven Covey about that.  Were I to guess, I'd guess it wasn't a conscious choice.  Unconsciously, maybe he said it that way to emphasize the humanity of others.  Sometimes, we as people tend to dehumanize others.  We stop seeing people as human beings and instead see them more like objects.  Maybe this emphasis was to remind us that that person is a human being, a human being who needs and deserves unconditional love.  That would be my take on it.

Comment: Thank you.I really liked the analogy of bank which made me understand deeply. After I read the first comment on the question, I thought like the quato  was not that deep but your point of view really opened a door to another understanding.IMHO, you didn't use the term "making  money out of thin air " but  it seems like "deposits of unconditional love" works in a similar way to whole society in a good way.I mean you give your love to someone but whole society may benefit from that unconditional love indirectly like ripples.

Comment: I must say, most surprisingly for BH this answer is basically totally wrong.  It would be as if an OP asked "What does it mean women are from Venus" and the answer literally explained, women have such and such qualities etc., and did not even mention that it's one of the basic "memes" in the field, a everyday catchphrase.

Comment: It would be as if someone asked "Why did Reagan name it star wars?" and the answer explained lasers and satellites, and did not even mention the film.

Comment: It would be as if someone asked .. well hell, you've got the idea  :)

Comment: Thus, Benjamin, you write ... *"he is writing to his audience. He is economizing love. He is figuratively quantifying love like it's money that can be put in a bank."*  This is, simply, completely wrong.  He's just ***using a current extremely popular catchphrase***. It couldn't be simpler.  (Indeed, he's playing on it a little by adding the "unconditional"! )

Comment: @Joe Blow : I'm going to have to beg to differ with you on this one.  The lines you draw about "paying it forward," which is about karma, and "love bank," which is about getting returns on love, exactly support what I've said. While you've gone on about it being an idiom, you haven't explained its meaning. Furthermore, I'd argue that it's not an idiom but merely metaphorical and figurative. Were it an idiom, the meaning couldn't be derived based on the words themselves, but it can be. Plus, you say it's not an idiom but an idiom "in the making." Saying a non-idiom idiom would make it nonsense.

Comment: First of all, let's set aside the difference between "catchphrase", and "idiom".  (Incidentally, as you may know, it drives me nuts when people use idiom incorrectly - when they simply mean figure of speech or catchphrase!) ....

Comment: So, what I'm saying is this very simple Benjamin:  "love deposits" is an **extremely common phrase** these days - it's a fad.  To not mention that in your answer is, well, madness!  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Joe Blow : I'm not saying that it is an "idiom."  You said it's an "idiom" in the making.  Moreover, if it does not mean exactly as I explained it, what then do you propose it means?  Whether you want to call it an idiom, an idiom in the making, a catch phrase (which it isn't), or whatever, what does it mean?  That is the OP's question.  What does it mean?  Incidentally, I know what it means.  I've said what it means.  Save your one downvote, the votes are tending to agree with me.  I'm just trying to cajole you into answering the question rather than go on about idioms and catch phrases.

Comment: (I used the word "idiom" once as a simile for "catchphrase" or "figure of speech" or "popular phrase" -- indeed I edited that away and just used "figure of speech". Sorry I ever used idiom, my mistake.  BTW note that idioms are of course figures of speech.)

Comment: Actually I completely changed my answer to make it simpler!  Thanks!!  You rock

Comment: Hi Benjamin, regarding your comment just above.  "love deposits" is an extremely common phrase these days - it's a fad. To not mention that in your answer is, well, madness!

Comment: @Joe Blow : Thanks you for saying so.  I've always wanted to rock.  *I wanna rock right now...*  Anyway, back to the point, you do realize that your updated answer, while glorious in its brevity, still does not answer the question.  It does not offer your surmising as to what Covey meant.  And my answer was madness?! Your answer was madness!  It was a crazy 40 or 50 lines of blah about idioms and catch phrases.  Now it's three, I don't know what to call them, *paragraphlets* about it being faddish and a figure of speech but still failing to answer the question.  Mad?! That's mad, cra-cra mad.

Answer (score 1):

'love deposits" is a popular, faddish, figure of speech particularly in US English.

(Simply [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=pay%20it%20forward&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=love%20deposits) 'love deposits' to see a huge number of popular books, articles, films, etc, using this phrase.)

(Covey happened to add "unconditional" to suggest a stronger sense...you could say it's his play on the common phrase.)